# How to use t2.nano ec2 instances in an Amazon ec2 container cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

The cluster wizard's dropdown menu only shows t2.micro or larger instances.
I want to use a t2.nano instance to run my docker image.

Can this be achieved while using the ec2 container service?

I know that can manually setup my own t2.nano ec2 instance and run the docker pull and run commands manually from there. Basically use the AWS EC2 Container repository, but not the Clusters or Task Definitions functionality.

Answer (score 2):

They probably missed this instance type in the console wizard. You can launch the EC2 instance yourself (I recommend you to use an AutoScaling Group even if it's one instance) and then run the ECS agent on the instance. You don't have to do much if you pick the ECS-optimized AMI that AWS provides.

You can launch the EC2 instance from the AMI manually, but I recommend you to:

1. create a Launch Configuration using the [latest ECS-optimized AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI_launch_latest.html) and change the user data to be:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "ECS_CLUSTER=your-cluster-name-here" > /etc/ecs/ecs.config
   ```
2. create an AutoScaling group and set the proper desired capacity
3. Check if your Cluster got the new instance once the instance is up and healthy

---

More info:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI_launch_latest.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html